# How to use rails with external web-service without DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

1. I have external web-service. This is API of big system core.
2. I want to use rails to develop interface for that API.
3. That API have advanced logic:

- There is a lot requests for check rights for different things.
- There is a lot requests with CRUD operations.
- There is a lot relations between hundreds entities.

Probably, I also dont need to use DB in rails app.

Can I just dont use Rails AR Models?

Where to store (dir) classes that works with external web service?

Where to store (dir) classes that works with data (data formatting) that I already requested from external web service? Not just views but like parsing, preparing data etc. All things that need to be prepared before view will be rendered.

Just for information there is example of what need to do:

0. Login only.
1. Add system user list. Where will be table with users and small data for each user.
2. Add user card (show). Where will be extended user information and actions for administrators.
3. Users can be viewed by all users by default.
4. There is specific rights where users can be hidden for specific users.
5. Users can be added only by administrator user.
6. Users can be edited only by administrator user.
7. User entity have relation with role entity, so add role list same page as user list.
8. Roles can be added only by administrator user.
9. Roles can be edited only by administrator user.

So request list is like:

1. System info request to show public system version or it status for example maintenance mode or just active.
2. Login request and show error response of incorrect data.
3. Current user data request.
4. Current user rights for user list request.
5. User list request if current user have rights.
6. Role list request if current user have rights.
7. Add new user request if current user have rights.
8. Edit any user request if current user have rights.
9. Add new role request if current user have rights.
10. Edit any role request if current user have rights.

Comment: So an [API only](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) rails?

Comment: I suggest having a look at [Rails' ActiveResource gem](https://github.com/rails/activeresource).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use rails? I have found [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) to be an excellent API library and you can run it as a Rack application.

Comment: @engineersmnky i want to use rails because there I also need to render all information that i receive from external service, I want to easy setup logic and just render something by controller. I like how rails do it.
Also, in the future it can be scalable and application will have own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're free to create a new Ruby on Rails application with the `--minimal` or even `--skip-active-record` flags.

> There is a lot requests for check rights for different things.

You may need an authorization library like Pundit and Cancancan.

> There is a lot relations between hundreds entities.

Don't you want to use ActiveRecord to keep track of relationships ? If it's what matter, you can only store primary and foreign keys

> Where to store (dir) classes that works with external web service?

IMHO, service objects (POROs)

> Where to store (dir) classes that works with data (data formatting) that I already requested from external web service?

Views ? Serializers ?

Comment: "Where to store (dir) classes that works with data (data formatting) that I already requested from external web service?".

Comment: "Where to store (dir) classes that works with data (data formatting) that I already requested from external web service?".

Not just views but like unserializing, parsing, preparing to view etc. All things that need to be prepared before view will be rendered.

Comment: You're free to add your own dir if you've specific needs. You could add a /app/deserializers if you want, or /app/parsers. Here's a resource I like when it comes to patterns: https://refactoring.guru/

I don't have any strong opinion about your needs though

Comment: "Don't you want to use ActiveRecord to keep track of relationships ? If it's what matter, you can only store primary and foreign keys".

I have updated post with example. Can I use AR objects without using DB methods to not store any data, but be able to use relations inside ruby code?

Comment: No, if you want to use `ActiveRecord::Associations`, you need to store keys somewhere. Plus, according to you edits, you'll want to use it anyway in order to allow users to sign-in and manage roles